# How to update select text with matched option value text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to update the select text with the selected option text after page load. 
Im redirecting on click of a option and after page load getting url from browser and checking which option has that value and wants to replace that matched option's text inside select text.

> ```
> <div class="sorting-option">
>    <select id="selectdropdown" class="dropdown-select">
>     <option value="">Recommended Items</option>
>     <option value="?sort1desc=F&sort1=Item_NAME">Name (A-Z)</option>
>     <option value="?sort1desc=T&sort1=Item_NAME">Name (Z-A)</option>
>     <option value=".f?sort1desc=F&sort1=Item_ONLINECUSTOMERPRICE">Price  
>     (Low-High)   
>     </option>
>     <option value=".f?sort1desc=T&sort1=Item_ONLINECUSTOMERPRICE">Price  
>     (High Low) 
>     </option>
>    </select>
>  </div>
> ```

This is what i have tried

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#selectdropdown').bind('change', function () {
location.href = $(this).val();
});
var brwsr_url=document.URL;
var subSting = brwsr_url.substring(brwsr_url.indexOf('?')); //here im getting substring of url to match with option value
$('#selectdropdown').find('option[value="subSting"]').text(); // here im trying to replace the select text with option text which has that url substring
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not concatenating properly. Also you're using getter of `text`. Instead, use the setter. Also from your comment, I suppose you need

```
$('#selectdropdown').val(subSting);
```

Comment: Yes its working but its not updating the select text with the matched option value text

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate>I think u are trying to select the option from the selectbox

```
$('#selectdropdown').find("option[value='"+subSting+"']").attr("selected","selected");
```